# div closing table inserting a line-break? how to prevent

Tags: html, css

Why does the following HTML insert a line break after the div closing tag?  how to prevent the line break from occurring so that it looks like extra simple table.

```html
<p>
<div style="width:200px">Keyword1</div> :About 1<br>
<div style="width:200px">Keyword2</div> :About 2<br>
</p>
```

I would have thought this produces:

```
Keyword1 : About 1
Keyword2 : About 2
```

instead it produces:

```
Keyword1 
: About 1
Keyword2 
: About 2
```

Answer (score 2):

this happen because `<div>` by default is `display: block;`,

 so you can override this by writing `display: inline;`

[image]

```html
<p>
  <div style="width:200px; display: inline;">Keyword1</div> :About 1<br>
  <div style="width:200px; display: inline;">Keyword2</div> :About 2<br>
</p>
```

---

---

---

however, I suggest something more structured  like this (since that code isn't a valid html)

```html
<div>
  <!-- 1 -->
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <span style="width: 200px">Keyword1</span>
    <span>:About 1</span>
  </div>
  <!-- 2 -->
  <div style="display: flex;">
    <span style="width: 200px">Keyword2</span>
    <span>:About 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

A `div` must not be child of a `p` tag - that's invalid HTML.

Also, div tags are block elements, which causes those linebreaks.

To use valid HTML, use `span`s instead of `div`s for inline elements. `span`s are inline by default, so add `display: inline-block` to them to have the possibility to apply a fixed `width` to them:

```html
<p>
  <span style="display: inline-block;width:200px;">Keyword1</span> :About 1<br>
  <span style="display: inline-block;width:200px;">Keyword2</span> :About 2<br>
</p>
```

P.S.:  You'd dbe better off using external CSS (using classes) instead of inline CSS on each element.

Answer (score -1):

div tag is block level element i would suggest to use

```css
display: inline
```

in styles